# Clickhouse http interface read Native/RowBinary Format data

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client, clickhouse-go

Want to get the query statistics info like rows_read/bytes_read for a query. But using the native interface(golang client), it seems impossible.
And using Http interface we could get it in the header returned. But using JSON/TabSeparated format, the server CPU seems cost much in encoding. So want to use the Native/RowBinary format instead to reduce the cost.
But don't find a recommended way to read and resolve the data...

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#rowbinary What language do you use? go-lang?